# Calculations with pandas Dataframe raising "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fill missing maximum temperature in a data frame usig the average and maximum temperature. I tried the following:

```
df.loc[df['Min Temperature']==np.NaN & df['Max Temperature']!=np.NaN & df['Average Temperature']!=np.NaN, df['Min Temperature']]=2*df['Average Temperature']-df['Max Temperature']
```

if `df['Min Temperature']==np.NaN` AND `Max` and `Average` Temperatures are available, set the value to:

```
2*df['Average Temperature']-(df['Max Temperature']
```

I am gettig the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

I tried to add float():

```
df.loc[df['Min Temperature']==np.NaN & df['Max Temperature']!=np.NaN & df['Average Temperature']!=np.NaN, df['Min Temperature']]=2*float(df['Average Temperature'])-float(df['Max Temperature'])
```

And I've got the following error:

> cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: to cast str values in series to float use as_type. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html

Comment: @RahulK `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''`

Answer (score 0):

Type casting can be done with `.astype()`:

```
2*(df['Average Temperature'].astype(float))-df['Max Temperature'].astype(float)
```

Comment: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''`